# Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"' when running pserve

Tags: pyramid

while trying pserve --help in virtual environment it is showing an error 
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'. 
It is working fine in global level but it is not working inside the virtual environment.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add operating system, Python version, full command and full output what you are trying to run.

Comment: it is windows 7, and working on python 2.7.12.  i activated the virtualenv as .\env\Scripts\activate  and trying to get the pyramid framework by using pcreate -s starter MyProject.  after trying this command i am getting this error.

Comment: It is working fine in global level but it is not working inside the virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had met the same problem when I use virtual environment, and try pip or pyinstaller, etc.. seems all the solution I had found were not suitalbe.
I noticed the problem sometimes would be the path error after I changed the venv path or folder structures.
And the solution is delete the old venv folder, and go to the project folder, re-create the venv.
Steps are:

1. python.exe -m venv venv or virtualenv venv
2. go to vevn\scripts to activate the venv
3. reinstall pyinstaller, pandas, the packages project needs
   Any excution must under venv activated.